# Python regex: Matching a URL

Tags: python, regex, url, imgur

I have some confusion regarding the pattern matching in the following expression. I tried to look up online but couldn't find an understandable solution:

```
imgurUrlPattern = re.compile(r'(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))(\?.*)?')
```

What exactly are the parentheses doing ? I understood up until the first asterisk , but I can't figure out what is happening after that.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out what the actual URL is based on the regex in your OP? If so, it's not really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))(\?.*)?
```

The first capturing group `(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))` means that the string should start with **http://i.imgur.com/** followed by any number of characters (`.*`) (this is a poor regex, you shouldn't do it this way). `(.*)` is also the second capturing group.

The third capturing group `(\?.*)` means that this part of the string must start with `?` and then contain any number of any characters, as above.

The last `?` means that the last capturing group is optional.

**EDIT**: 
These groups can then be used as:

```
p = re.compile(r'(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))(\?.*)?')
m = p.match('ab')
m.group(0);
m.group(2);
```

To improve the regex, you must limit the engine to what characters you need, like:

```
(http://i.imgur.com/([A-z0-9\-]+))(\?[[^/]+*)?
```

> `[A-z0-9\-]+` limit to alphanumeric characters
>   `[^/]` exclude `/`

Comment: So basically,each parentheses is a group? 
Also, what would you suggest to improve the poor regex and why is it bad :s?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions can be represented as graphs to understand there operation. A parallel connection between nodes indicate that it is optional a serial connection indicates taht it is mandatory and a loop indicated repitition over the same node.

```
(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))(\?.*)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ah_JGQiHaD5bRZQC)

So this starts with an imgur URL http://i.imgur.com/(.*) (mandatorily) having any characters untill a '?'(optional) is encountered.  Following any characters after the '?'. Notice '?' has been escaped of its regular behaviour. The pink highlights indicate the **capture groups**.

Answer (score 1):

The `(.*)` means any character repeated any amount of times, the (\?.*)? matches the query string of a url for example (a imgur search of "cat"):

```
http://imgur.com/search?q=cat
```

`http://imgur.com/search` is matched by the `(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))` (the `search` is specifically matched by the `(.*)`) section of the regex.  The `?q=cat` is matched by the `(\?.*)?` of the regex.  In the regex the ? in the end means optional, so it means there might or might not be a query string.  There is no query string in the url `http://www.imgur.com`.  The parenthesis are used for grouping.  We want to group `(http://i.imgur.com/(.*))` as one thing because it matches the url, and there is another group within this that matches the page you are request (this is `(.*)`). We want to group `(\?.*)?` because it matches the query string.

Here is a diagram to help you
[image]